# ExecutorService thread-pool size for web application accessed concurrently by multiple users

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, executorservice

We have a Java web service application deployed in tomcat. The server is 3 core and 7gb RAM. 
Its in cloud with auto scaling enabled up to 20 instances.
This web service will be accessed by minimum 1000 users simultaneously at any given point of time.

Now coming to the web service code, it needs to process 15 different methods parallely(each method on an average takes 3 secs) , wait for all the methods to give back response, process all the response and give back an output to the calling client. We use Java Executor Service with FixedThreadPool for the same.

Questions:

1. Is it good idea to initiate the FixedThreadPool Executor at Servlet init() method and shut it down at servlet destroy so that thread pool is initialized once and application uses threads from this pool
2. What should be the Fixed Thread Pool size?? Should it be a very high number in range of  1k or 2k since there are multiple clients calling the web service simultaneously??  Or should it be a smaller number ? How should we come up with a thread pool size so that all 1000 clients accessing the web service get back the response without delay or wait.
3. Should we go for a cached thread pool for our scenario and not worry about pool size?

Kindly help.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it good idea to initiate the FixedThreadPool Executor at Servlet init() method and shut it down at servlet destroy so that thread pool is initialized once and application uses threads from this pool

You can certainly do this but it is more typical to initialize a global thread pool and then have each request share the same pool.  If you optimize the number of threads in the pool (see below) it will be hard to coordinate the requests being executed in parallel if they each have their own pool.

That said, if you need to fork a number of threads and then wait for them to finish, it may be easier to use a pool per request – especially if these requests take a long time to run meaning that the pool creation is a small part of the overall work.

> What should be the Fixed Thread Pool size?

This is a very hard question to answer without a lot more information about the work in question.  Typically you increase the number of threads if the requests are very IO bound – waiting for network connections for example.  1-2k threads might work but if the goal is to queue *none* of the jobs then I'd use a cached thread pool of course.

If you are maxing out the CPU of the server then you should reduce the number of threads because you might be running too many jobs concurrently which may reduce your overall throughput.  It also should be taken into account if all of the 15 jobs must be running at the same time.

> How should we come up with a thread pool size so that all 1000 clients accessing the web service get back the response without delay or wait.

Just adding more threads doesn't necessarily make things go faster.  It's about throughput.  If possible you should model your requests or maybe try some settings in production and then compare requests per second, etc. to determine which thread-pool settings result in the highest overall throughput.

> Should we go for a cached thread pool for our scenario and not worry about pool size?

You certainly could however what you worry about is that you'll get a bump in the number of requests which would cause a huge number of threads to be started.  Again, there will be an optimal number of threads that are running in the server and handling requests.  Too many threads will not make the jobs finish faster and since they take up resources and increase the context switch frequency, can easily reduce the overall throughput.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. Thanks for the detailed explanation. Will try the suggested approaches and see what fits our case better. Thanks !